# Web API 2 and Swagger

Tags: swagger, .net-core-2.2

I have a web api created in .Net Core 2.2, I added the swagger and it is working perfectly, but I want to make some customizations in the documentation.

I have some viewsmodels that I use is the same to receive the request as for the response, so Swagger displays some properties that are not required in the post, as example below:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string TokenJWT { get; set; }
    }
```

In Swagger when I did the test for the post displays TokenJWT, but in the post this is not required, I do not want it to be displayed, after the post successfully returned the same viewmodel informing the generated token, so the property exists. How to do this without creating a viewmodel for request and another for response?